# Jest fails to run .tsx files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

I implemented typescript to my create-react-app project and I can't run jest test files with .jsx suffix to test .tsx files

for example I want to test `ConsentContainer.tsx` file with `ConsentContainer.spec.jsx` and I got this error

```
test/unit/containers/ConsentContainer.spec.jsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token
```

.
.
.

```
  Details:

    C:\src\containers\ConsentContainer.tsx:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { useEffect, useState }
from 'react';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import React from 'react';
      2 | import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
    > 3 | import ConsentContainer from '../../../src/containers/ConsentContainer';
```

when the files had .jsx suffix jest tests worked properly
but I don't know how to make the configuration

tsconfig.json

```
  {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
          "es6",
          "dom",
          "dom.iterable",
          "esnext"
        ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
      },
      "include": [
        "src"
      ]
    }
```

jest.config.json

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFiles: ['raf/polyfill'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./test/jest.test-setup.js'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'tsx'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'identity-obj-proxy'
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/cypress/', '/.cache/Cypress/3.1.0/Cypress/'],
  snapshotSerializers: ['enzyme-to-json/serializer'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|css!|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$':
        'jest-transform-stub',
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
        '<rootDir>/test/assetsTransformer.js'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/(?!(p-retry)/)',
    '/dist/'
  ]
};
```

babel.config.json

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-typescript"],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
      "regenerator": true
    }],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```

when I install ts-jest package all my tests are failing not only ones connected with .tsx files